# Rails 4, pushing app to Heroku, no CSS and no JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have pushed my rails 4 app to heroku, everythings works fine.

i have created a staging app by forking the original production app and i have named it "staging".
Now i have 2 apps: production and staging.

to have the same configuration I copied
config/environments/production.rb in config/environments/staging.rb .

i have pushed in heroku:

```
git push staging master
```

but the problem is in staging app i have no css and no js, but in production app i have both.

this is my production.rb file

```
#config/environments/production.rb
CentroservizirovigoCom::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  config.eager_load = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  config.assets.digest = true

  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  config.log_level = :info

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
 config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

 end
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Can you paste in your environmental configs both for staging and production?

Comment: ok, i have posted the production.rb file. The staging is a copy of production. The production works